# Apache becomes unresponsive when serving php

Tags: apache-2.2, php, amazon-ec2

I'm having this strange problem on my c1.medium EC2 instance where Apache serves static files very well (as per `tail -f access_log`).

But, the `php` files don't open after a few initial requests, which are successfully fulfilled.

There are enough server resources for apache to run properly. I'm feebly experienced with Apache configuration and this is a strange problem.

Comment: Take a look at the error log.

Comment: Had nothing in it. Already checked.

Answer (score 0):

Is it **all** php files?  If you create a very small PHP file (i.e. "hello world" type), does it slow down too?

Dan

Comment: I ran a `phpinfo()` and it worked. Surprisingly!